# Integrate Twilio Chat feature in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: xamarin.forms, twilio

I’m currently developing a Xamarin Forms (to target both Android and iPhone) mobile application (code sharing strategy – .NET Standard) and I want to integrate Twilio Chat feature into it.  While searching for related documents I have seen some posts (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-build-android-chat-apps-using-xamarin-and-twilio.html) and looks outdated. I have tried to add the "Twilio IP Messaging for Xamarin" package from Nuget but it's not listing out there. While searching I have found a similar package called "Twilio.Chat.Xamarin"(https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatXamarinBindings) but it seems to be native and using shared code sharing strategy. Some of them say (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/issues/21#issuecomment-468183784) that support for .NET Standard is not available at the moment. Is this true? Are there any methods to integrate Twilio chat feature into .NET Standard Xamarin Forms project? It would be nice if you can share your thoughts or some links so that I can take a look.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got response from Twilio support:

> Unfortunately, Twilio does not fully support Xamarin, our team has
>   authored Xamarin bindings which can be found here:
>   https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatXamarinBindings. That being said,
>   Twilio Support can only provide support for our JS SDK which the
>   Xamarin bindings make use of.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get anywhere with this? I have the same requirement.